# Setting ImageView weight to 50% of screen in center

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout

I have an Imageview and want to set the width of this to 50% of the screen size. But the Image should placed in the middle of the screen. This is what I did:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/logoView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/app_logo_login" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Because of the `layout_weight` the width of the image is perfect. My problem is, that the height of the image is way too much, to understand what I mean, see this picture:

[image]

For some reason, the height of the picture is not decreasing and it still has the original height even though I see it scaled. How to fix that?

Comment: `ImageView` has attribute called `scaleType`. If I understood what you want correctly, you need to set it to `centerCrop` but you can play around with the values until you get the result that satisfies you.

Comment: @nstosic: I already played with `scaleType` bit couldn't make it work with that.

Comment: @pskink I don't need to do that.. I have realized that the view height is not how I want it....that is why I am asking how to fix this. But thanks for the hint :)

Comment: @pskink I see them already....It is the blue border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Constraint layout with guidlines

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />
```

Comment: using app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio, you can set your image height with respect to width.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `ConstraintLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/app_logo_login" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can read the [documentation of ConstrainLayout](https://constraintlayout.com/).

Comment: And how do I get it to have 50% width?

Comment: @progNewbie You can use PercentLayout for that. With 2 guidelines at 25% from each side => https://constraintlayout.com/layouts/percentlayout.html

Comment: Constraint your image to vertical guidlines.Check my answer

Comment: @KevinRobatel Percent layout is deprecated in 26+

Comment: @svkaka PercentLayout from ConstraintLayout lib is a new thing. It's not PercentRelativeLayout ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please find this one:
Make parent linear layout match parent for both width and height with horizontal orientation

```
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/splash" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>
```